# amanda: No space left on device -- which device?

Tags: backup, amanda

I was in the middle of an amanda backup, and after about 100GB, it exited with this error:

```
michelle-laptop /cygdrive/c/Users lev 0  FAILED [data write: Connection reset by peer]
michelle-laptop /cygdrive/c/Users lev 0  partial taper: No space left on device: No space left on device
michelle-laptop /cygdrive/c/Users lev 0  FAILED [data write: Broken pipe]
michelle-laptop /cygdrive/c/Users lev 0  partial taper: No space left on device: No space left on device
```

But it doesn't tell me which device.  And I can't find any device that is full.

My backup ended after 100GB

```
-rw-------   1 amanda backup       32768 2016-10-21 23:07 00000.MyData133
-rw-------   1 amanda backup 65880096768 2016-10-22 10:13 00001.michelle-laptop._cygdrive_c_Users.0
-rw-------   1 amanda backup 34365898752 2016-10-22 16:25 00002.michelle-laptop._cygdrive_c_Users.0
```

My amanda.conf says

```
tapetype "HARD-DISK"
define tapetype HARD-DISK {
    comment "Dump onto hard disk"
    length 150 gbytes
}
```

My backup drive has space

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1             2.7T  2.3T  268G  90% /storage
```

The disk being backed up has space

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:/cygwin64     233G  164G   70G  71% /
```

How do I find out what happened?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody cares, I figured out what I think is the answer via trial-and-error.

My config specifies

```
tapetype "HARD-DISK"
define tapetype HARD-DISK {
    comment "Dump onto hard disk"
    length 125 gbytes
}
```

for my virtual tapes, and also has

```
runtapes 2
```

So when my device got below 250GB free (the size of two empty virtual-tapes), I got the error.

I need to make sure there is enough room on my external drive to complete the backup **and** have 250GB free.